# Error in querying a remote Oracle Database from Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: oracle, pentaho, report-designer

I'm trying to get some data from a remote Oracle Database,
so I configured a new connection to the database and whn I press Test, it says that the connection was established succesfully, but when i tried a simple select query, Report Designer gives me an error:

```
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query: select * from fact_table;
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:258)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SQLReportDataFactory.java:171)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcPreviewWorker.run(JdbcPreviewWorker.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

ParentException:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:305)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:272)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:623)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CStatement.java:351)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CStatement.java:383)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doScrollExecuteCommon(OracleStatement.java:3763)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doScrollStmtExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:3887)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1131)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.parametrizeAndQuery(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:422)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:254)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SQLReportDataFactory.java:171)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcPreviewWorker.run(JdbcPreviewWorker.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So how can I get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select * from fact_table;` seems to be a valid query. Try to remove the semicolon at the end.